# Print to a Dot-Matrix Printer directly from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing, epson, dot-matrix

i am finishing a program i am writing and i have to create a printing to an Epson LQ-300+ Dot-Matrix. The printing has to print some text in some specific parts of the paper (Amount,name etc)
Can anyone point me to the right direction or post me an example since i was not able to find something in order to send directly the ASCII characters to the printer via LPT1.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT Is going to be mainly trial and error a far as positioning goes, it is also going to depend on the font and wether or not you are using a Generic/Text Driver (*if so the character spacing, line spacing and font are what ever the printer has been setup for*). Back in the DOS days you could send out individual characters to the printer but printing in windows is page based meaning you will need to use the [PrintDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), handle the [PrintPage event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  using the [PrintPageEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [Graphic Property's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) [PrintString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c36z9t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to position the text where you need it to be.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If PrintDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World", New Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black, New Point(100, 100))
End Sub
```